# Hangman guessed letters issue

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and am having an issue with displaying the guessed letters in my Hangman game. When the user clicks on the "guess" button, the checkinput() method should start, and this should run:

```
//loop through word and if guess equals the character of the inputted work, replace - with letter. 
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        //if user's guess is matched against one of the letters of the word, this will execute. 
        if (guess == input.substring(i, i + 1)) {
            placeholder = placeholder.substring(0, i) + guess + placeholder.substring(i + 1, placeholder.length);
            spguess.innerHTML = placeholder;
            //if guessed letter is wrong, push into wrongg array
        } else if (guess != input.substring(i, i + 1)){ 
            wrongg.push(guess);
            console.log(wrongg);
            }
        }
    }
```

The else if part is where I am having issues. I would like to be able to console.log the guessed letters(incorrect letters that don't match the inputted word). Could you point me in the right direction? https://jsfiddle.net/gdbn47or/ is the jsfiddle

Comment: Couldn't you just do `input.indexOf(guess)`?

Comment: Indeed, as @gcampbell mentioned, your approach for this problem is not correct. You don't need the loops - you can just look up the character the user entered by using `string.indexOf(character)`. Alternatively, on modern browsers, if you just want to check if a `String` contains a `Character`, you can write `String.includes(character)`. So for example: `"hello".includes("l")` will return 'true'. (But this is only supported in modern browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having problems i think because you have your wrongg.push inside the cycle, so even when the guess is right for the forth letter, it will still enter the wrongg array 3 or even more times, what you should do is for each cycle you should have a boolean (found), then change your if to:

```
    if (guess == input.substring(i, i + 1)) {
        placeholder = placeholder.substring(0, i) + guess + placeholder.substring(i + 1, placeholder.length);
        spguess.innerHTML = placeholder;
        found = true;
    }
```

Then only do the else if part after the for cycle if the found boolean is false